# Oracle: Select at least one record foreach cluster

Tags: sql, oracle

Look at the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ENI_FLUSSI_HUB c1
WHERE flh_tipo_processo_cod IN ('VA', 'NUOVA_ATT_ENI')
AND rownum < 10
```

It simply extracts just some VA. I need the extract some VA and some NUOVA_ATT_ENI.

What is the most elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ENI_FLUSSI_HUB c1
WHERE flh_tipo_processo_cod = 'VA'
AND rownum < 5

UNION 

SELECT *
FROM ENI_FLUSSI_HUB c1
WHERE flh_tipo_processo_cod = 'NUOVA_ATT_ENI'
AND rownum < 5
```

---

Is there aren't any duplicate values, you can use `UNION ALL` to perform faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM ENI_FLUSSI_HUB c1
WHERE flh_tipo_processo_cod = 'VA'
AND rownum < 5

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM ENI_FLUSSI_HUB c1
WHERE flh_tipo_processo_cod = 'NUOVA_ATT_ENI'
AND rownum < 5
```

---

As @DavidAldridge stated, you can always use a `view` to make this selection.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I've used `UNION` to get 5 different results from each one. `UNION ALL` won't remove duplicates.

Comment: yes, but if the query is complex I have to duplicate it. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Gik25 like you can see by David's answer, it's the easiest way to understand it :) and you'll always have to duplicate it somewhere.

Comment: Duplicates are impossible since it uses `SELECT *` flh_tipo_processo_cod is in the output, and differentiated in the `WHERE` clause, so `UNION ALL` can only do good, and no harm.

Comment: Ah, but the the original query doesn't de-duplicate the result so I think that the answer shopuldn't, either because there is a primary key that makes it irrelevant or because the result is not required to be distinct.

Comment: If the query is complex then you could simplify your code with a view.

Comment: @DavidAldridge you simply can't assume that because he didn't use distinct. But I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Gik25 If it is really complex make the query a view? Or move the query to a Common Table Expression and query that, but I am in agreement with aF here, this is the simplest and most elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nicely overengineered solution:

```
with
  va as (
    select rowid ri,
           t.*
    from   eni_flussi_hub t
    where  flh_tipo_processo_cod = 'VA'
    and    rownum <= 1),
  nuova_att_eni as (
    select rowid ri,
           t
    from   eni_flussi_hub t
    where  flh_tipo_processo_cod = 'NUOVA_ATT_ENI'
    and    rownum <=1),
  the_rest as (
    select *
    from   eni_flussi_hub c1
    where  flh_tipo_processo_cod in ('VA','NUOVA_ATT_ENI')
    and    rowid not in (
             select ri
             from   va
             union all
             select ri
             from nuova_att_eni)
    and rownum <=9)
select *
from  (
      select * from va
      union all
      select * from nuova_att_eni
      union all
      select * from the_rest
      )
where rownum <= 10
/
```

I *think* that what it does is return at least one row for each of the two values of flh_tipe_processo_cod, and "lets nature take its course" with the rest.

You'd have to edit the *'s in the main query to avoid trying to include the rowid from the first two subquery factoring clauses.

Here's another, which *I think* attempts to bring back five of each but will "top up" the required total if less than five are available for either of the two subquery factoring clauses:

```
with
  va as (
    select rownum rn,
           t.*
    from   eni_flussi_hub t
    where  flh_tipo_processo_cod = 'VA'
    and    rownum <= 10),
  nuova_att_eni as (
    select rownum rn,
           t
    from   eni_flussi_hub t
    where  flh_tipo_processo_cod = 'NUOVA_ATT_ENI'
    and    rownum <=10)
select *
from  (
      select *
      from   (select * from va
              union all
              select * from nuova_att_eni)
      order by rn asc
      )
where rownum <= 10
/
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Depends how complex the requirement is! Is it to get at least one of each, or to try to get the same number of each, and what if one of them returns less than 5 rows ... should the shortfall be made up from the other?